# Using float makes my app crash in Android

Tags: android

I was following a OpenGL tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html#angle) and I did everything right I think. But my code crashes on `mRenderer.setAngle(mRenderer.getAngle() +((dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR));`

**Edit I also added this to get the height and width**

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
final int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
final int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Code:

```
public class OpenGL extends Fragment {
    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;
    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;
    OpenGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public OpenGL() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(getActivity());
        mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLView.setRenderer(new OpenGLRenderer());
        // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
        mGLView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        final int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        final int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        mGLView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

                // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
                // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
                // interested in events where the touch position changed.

                float x = e.getX();
                float y = e.getY();

                switch (e.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                        float dy = y - mPreviousY;

                        // reverse direction of rotation above the mid-line
                        if (y > height / 2) {
                            dx = dx * -1;
                        }

                        // reverse direction of rotation to left of the mid-line
                        if (x < width / 2) {
                            dy = dy * -1;
                        }

                        mRenderer.setAngle(
                                mRenderer.getAngle() +
                                        ((dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR));
                        mGLView.requestRender();
                }
                mPreviousX = x;
                mPreviousY = y;
                return true;
            }
        });
        return mGLView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLView.onPause();
    }
}
```

OpenGLRenderer Class

```
class OpenGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private Triangle mRectangle;
    // mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
    float[] scratch = new float[16];
    public volatile float mAngle;

    public float getAngle() {
        return mAngle;
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        mAngle = angle;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        //GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        mRectangle = new Triangle();
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        // Create a rotation for the triangle
        // long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
        // float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
        Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);

        // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
        // Note that the mMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
        // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

        // Draw triangle
        mRectangle.drawMatrix(scratch);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }
}
```

Triangle Class

```
class Triangle {
    private final String vertexShaderCodeMatrix =
     // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
     // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
     "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
             "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
             "void main() {" +
             // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
             // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
             // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
             "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
             "}";

    // Use to access and set the view transformation
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;


    private final String vertexShaderCode =
         "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                 "void main() {" +
                 "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                 "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
         "precision mediump float;" +
                 "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                 "void main() {" +
                 "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                 "}";

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
         0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f, // top
         -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f, // bottom left
         0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f  // bottom right
    };

    // Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
    float color[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };

    private final int mProgram;

    private short[] indices = {0,1,2,0,2,3};

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;

    public Triangle() {

         // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
         ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                 // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                 triangleCoords.length * 4);
         // use the device hardware's native byte order
         bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

         // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
         vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
         // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
         vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
         // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
         vertexBuffer.position(0);

         int vertexShader = OpenGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                 vertexShaderCode);
         int fragmentShader = OpenGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                 fragmentShaderCode);

         // create empty OpenGL ES Program
         mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

         // add the vertex shader to program
         GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

         // add the fragment shader to program
         GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

         // creates OpenGL ES program executables
         GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
    }

    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;

    private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    public void draw() {
        // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
             GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
             vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

    public void drawMatrix(float[] mvpMatrix) { // pass in the calculated transformation matrix


         // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
         GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

         // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
         mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

         // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
         GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

         // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
         GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                 vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

         // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
         mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

         // Set color for drawing the triangle
         GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

         // Draw the triangle
         GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

         // Disable vertex array
         GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

         // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
         mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

         // Pass the projection and view transformation to the shader
         GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

         // Draw the triangle
         GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

         // Disable vertex array
         GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
}
```

> 04-26 10:55:22.153 31562-31562/com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
>   04-26 10:55:22.153 31562-31562/com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
>   04-26 10:55:22.174 31562-31562/com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.OpenGLRenderer.getAngle()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                              at com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.OpenGL$1.onTouch(OpenGL.java:95)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10019)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1808)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:375)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10243)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4438)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4306)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3999)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4056)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6246)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6220)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6181)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6349)
>                                                                                              at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   04-26 10:55:22.204 31562-31562/com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android, PID: 31562
>                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.OpenGLRenderer.getAngle()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                            at com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.OpenGL$1.onTouch(OpenGL.java:95)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10019)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:413)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1808)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
>                                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:375)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10243)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4438)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4306)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3999)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4056)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3872)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3853)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6246)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6220)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6181)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6349)
>                                                                                            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                                            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize the `mRenderer` ...variable

```
OpenGLRenderer mRenderer;
```

that's why `mRenderer.getAngle()` gives you a null pointer exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'float com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.OpenGLRenderer.getAngle()'
>   on a null object reference

try initialize it in your `onCreateView()`

```
mRenderer = new OpenGLRenderer();
```

Comment: dont crash now but doesnt rotate either xD

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405466/android-help-rotating-image-on-touch